# Ajax failing multiple times before it works

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a very annoying bug. My AJAX queries are failing anywhere up to 20-30 times with 500 GET and POST server errors, but then all of a sudden they work.

It seems to be completely random, as sometimes I will load the page and it will work fine for a full day of usage, but then the next day it will fail and I have to catch and retry it up to 30 times to get it to work.

AJAX

```
 function getData(){
//Get Data and build contributions Table
$.ajax({
        url: 'assets/processes/dash/support/get-data.php', // URL of php command
        tryCount : 0,
        retryLimit : 3,
        type: 'POST', //TYPE
        data: {'id': id}, //Variables in JSON FORMAT
        success: function(results) { //SUCCESSFUL REQUEST FUNCTION
          var result = $.parseJSON(results);
          console.log(result);
        },
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                    this.tryCount++;
                    if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                        $.ajax(this);
                        return;
                    }            
                    return;
                }
                if (xhr.status == 500) {
                    $.ajax(this);
                    return;
                } else {
                    //handle error
                }
       }
      }); // end ajax call
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 include "../../../includes/database.php";
 $totalOpen = $db->pdo_query_assoc("xdGetTotalUnresolvedTickets 
 1,0,0,0,0,0");
 $totalWaitState = $db->pdo_query_assoc("xdGetWaitState 1,0,0,0,0,0");
 $nonWaitState = $totalOpen['xdGetTotalUnresolvedTickets'] - 
 $totalWaitState['xsGetWaitState'];
 $getStaff = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE role = 'Technical 
 Support'");
 $getStaffArray = array();
  foreach($getStaff as $key => $value){
      $sqlUsername = $value['sqlName'];
      $pdo_today = $db->pdo_query_assoc("xsGetTotalResolvedTicketsToday 
      '$sqlUsername'");
      $start = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('-7 days'));
      $end = date('Y-m-d ', strtotime('+1 days'));
      $pdo_last_week = $db->pdo_query_assoc("xsGetTotalResolvedTicketsToday 
      '$sqlUsername','$start','$end'");
      $getCompletionRate = $db->pdo_query_assoc('xStaffTicketCompletionRate 
      "'.$sqlUsername.'"');
      $getWeeklyRate = $db->pdo_query_assoc('xLastSevenPreviousSeven 
      "'.$sqlUsername.'"');
      $getStaffArray[$key]['staffName'] = $value['user'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['staffFullName'] = $value['name'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['colourScheme'] = $value['colourScheme'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['today'] = 
      $pdo_today['xsGetTotalResolvedTicketsToday'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['thisWeek'] = 
      $pdo_last_week['xsGetTotalResolvedTicketsToday'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['completionRate'] = $getCompletionRate['Level'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['thisTimeLastWeek'] = 
      round($getWeeklyRate['Percentage'],1);
      $getStaffArray[$key]['weeklyRateLevel'] = $getWeeklyRate['Level'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['weeklyPrevious7'] = $getWeeklyRate['Previous 7 
      Days'];
      $getStaffArray[$key]['weeklyEarlier7'] = $getWeeklyRate['Earlier 7 
      Days'];
   }
  $tickets = array('totalCurrent' => $totalOpen, 'totalWaitState' => 
  $totalWaitState, 'totalNoneWaitState' => $nonWaitState);
  $allData = array('totalTickets' => $tickets, 'staff' => $getStaffArray);
  echo json_encode($allData, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  ?>
```

I know at the moment the trycount doesnt work properly, as instead of trying 3 times it tries unlimited amount until it works. Any one have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

They always fail on the php file, like the query cant be executed.

ERROR

```
  GET     http://mysite/get-events.php 500 (Internal Server Error)    
  jquery.min.js:4
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the page that is throwing the internal server error?

Comment: Debug your php. Add error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the page to get any errors back if you don't already.

Comment: You should check your error log. And how can the error you have shown come from the script if it is a POST request and not a GET request? And I am not sure what `$.ajax(this)` will do exactly...

Comment: Funnily enough @jeroen thats something thats quite bizarre, I get a lot of both GET and POST errors, but I dont have a single ajax querie that is using the GET method?

Comment: @Adriani6 Sorry for sounding stupid but how do i handle/see the errors after adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to my code?

Comment: @Sam You should be returned an error on the page, try accessing it by removing any POST parameters for a fast debug.

Comment: @Adriani6 ah of course, i think I have `display_errors:off` in my ini file. Ill change it and look.

Comment: @Adriani6 nevermind, I have my `display_errors` on but i'm not getting any errors.

Comment: If I load the php pages directly in my url, they work everytime.

Comment: @Sam How big is your json output?

Comment: @Adriani6 some are very large, but some are also not that large, and it seems to be erroring and failing randomly on scripts. If I have 5 scripts, every time i refresh, some will work and some wont. Could it be something to do with them all trying to load at the same time?

Comment: @Sam no, the error specifies that there's an error on the php page. My assumption is that the JSON returned is too big to transfer.

Comment: @Adriani6 If that was the case, how would it work sometimes and not others? And how would i get around it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154970/discussion-between-adriani6-and-sam).